# How to disable spelling corrections programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, spell-checking

How can I disable spelling corrections in an `EditText`'s soft-keyboard programmatically in Android? The user can disable it from settings, but I need to disable it in my application.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I want to disable it. it makes difficultly typing

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Set this in your layout's xml for your EditText:

`android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`

Or call `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)` in your Activity'

If you need to support API 4 and below, use `android:inputType="textFilter"`

Answer (score 10):

If setting:

```
 android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

still doesn't work (and your text field is small), a quick work-around is to use:

```
 android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```