# How to disable dictionary mode in android phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to disable spell correction programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330234/how-to-disable-spell-correction-programmatically-in-android)

I need to disable the dictionary programatically. How do I do this?

Comment: Show what you did for achieving your solution

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330234/how-to-disable-spell-correction-programmatically-in-android

Comment: i need to remove the dictionary mode by programatically

Comment: while typing in the textbox the dicinoary window is open.i need to remove that dictionary window

Comment: How to do this in android phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in your activity

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)
```

Comment: am getting error like this - The method setInputType(int) is undefined for the type   AndroidActivity