# Android app underlines misspelled words

Tags: android, textview, spell-checking, underline, misspelling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to disable spell correction programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330234/how-to-disable-spell-correction-programmatically-in-android)

I have created an app that displays slang words on the screen, such as wassup and yessir.  These words are displayed in a textview, and appear underlined when the app is run on my device because they clearly are not in the dictionary.  I do not want this.

In the below code, question[i] is a string array that contains the slang:

```
        LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = li.inflate(R.layout.answersrow, null);

        TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.answer);
        Qname=question[i];
        tv.setText(Qname);
```

Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried searching for this problem on Stack Overflow already?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to set, in the editText's xml:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```