# How to remove the double underline from EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I cant find a solution to remove the white line at the bottom of the text.

[image]

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/7336819/8089770

Comment: White line is of the suggested word.

Comment: android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" solve the problem

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod How it could be duplicate if he does not know that is spell correction or words suggestion?