# how to enable and disable spell check programmatically in android?

Tags: android

How can I disable spelling corrections in an EditText's soft-keyboard programmatically in Android? The user can disable it from settings, but I need to disable it in my application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable spelling corrections programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330234/how-to-disable-spelling-corrections-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Android provides a Spell Check service by default.
To disable this service:
**For TextView:**

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

**For EditText:**

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Or programatically in activity:

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)
```

If your EditText is multiline:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
```

For the android version **8.0 or above** :

```
android:importantForAutofill="no"
```

**textNoSuggestions** does not work in every keyboard. So you can check with `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"` or `android:inputType="textUri”`.

Comment: If you find helpful answer ,you should accept answer and close the question.

Comment: Fantastic answer.